# Error while executing an existing Python code which works in other machine in Windows

Tags: python-3.x

C:\Windows\system32>E:\Python\python.exe E:\sapbo_job_monitoring\script\sql_Windows_AD_Failed.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
return fn()
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py",

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please look at [this page on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your revert. I am new to this forum. Actually I was not able to put the full error message here as it was giving indentation error.  Error was coming as below while executing Python script cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password + ';Trusted_Connection=no;')
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (1)')